# PHP - Content type header setup not reflecting in the response

Tags: php, api, rest, mime-types

I am using tomcat and apache(PHP, slim framework) to run some APIs. For some APIs PHP apis will call java apis using curl request and send the response back to the user. Here there is an API in JAVA which returns a pdf attachment as a downloadable file where I have set Content-Type as "Content-Type: APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM". And in php api, when returning this response to user I am setting the Content-Type to same but when user requests, the content-type coming as text/html. Because of this the download is failing in mobile browsers(tested in mobile chrome) but working in desktop browsers. When I directly request Java API, I am getting proper content-type and I am able to download.

I have tried setting content-type in php but it seems its not changing from text/html. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and where else I need to change.

Here is the code.

JAVA response with file download:

```
//send the file in response to download
                response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+nameOfFile+"");
                
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                
                
                int i=0;
                while((i = fileInputStream.read()) != -1){
                    out.write(i);
                }
                
                
                inputStream.close();
                fileInputStream.close();
                out.close();
```

Here is the PHP api code

```
 function DownloadReport($request, $response, $args)
    {
        $path = $request->getUri()->getPath();
        $path = str_ireplace("v1/", "", $path);

        $query = $request->getParsedBody();
        if(is_null($query)){
           $query = $request->getQueryParams();
        }
        $url = Constants::$BASE_URL . $path;
        $result = Constants::sendCurlRequestForFileStream($url, "post", $query);
        if ($result['status'] == "200") {
            $fileName = "Lead_".strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')).".pdf";

            header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename='.$fileName);
            header("Content-type: APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");

            return $result['data'];
        } else {
            return $response->withJson($result['data'], Constants::$UNAUTHORIZED_CODE);
        }
    }
```

In the above code I am setting content-type header before returning the data, but still in the response I am seeting `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`.

And here is the Curl request code

```
public static function sendCurlRequestForFileStream($url,$method,$fields=null){
        $result['message'] = "";
        $result['status'] = Constants::$SUCCESS_CODE;

        //Initializing curl to open a connection
        $ch = curl_init();
        if($method=="post"){
            //building headers for the request
            $headers = array(
                'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            );
            $req = "";
            foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
                if (is_array($value)) {
                    foreach ($value as $val) {
                        $req .= $key.'[]='.urlencode($val).'&';
                    }
                }
                else{
                    $req .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&';
                }
            }
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
            //setting the method as post
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

        }elseif($method=="get"){
            $headers = array(
                'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            );
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
        }

        //Setting the curl url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        //adding headers
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        //disabling ssl support
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        //finally executing the curl request
        $curlExecuteStatus = curl_exec($ch);
        $response = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($response != Constants::$SUCCESS_CODE) {
            $result['message'] = "Failed to get result.";
            $result['status'] = $response;
            $result['data'] = $curlExecuteStatus;
        } else {
            $result['message'] = "success";
            $result['status'] = $response;
            $result['data'] = $curlExecuteStatus;
        }

        //Now close the connection
        curl_close($ch);
        //and return the result
        return $result;
    }
```

Please let me know if anymore information is needed to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled? No “headers already sent” errors anywhere?

Comment: The error reporting is already enabled and I have checked the error logs of apache but couldn't find any errors regarding this API call. Also “headers already sent” error not logged anywhere.

Comment: So what is the method `DownloadReport` returning _to_? Maybe the Content-Type header gets overwritten at a later point?

Comment: DownloadReport method directly returns to user. I am using slim framework, so from routes I am calling DownloadReport when the API request comes. I checked all other files but couldn't find any. Do you know if I should check any other configuration files?

Comment: Could you try instead of `return $result['data'];` `echo $result['data']; exit();`. That way you can rule out whether anything else in the framework is changing the headers after the return. You may need to set other headers like 'Content-length' if you are exiting there.